# Making an SVG path that looks like two, while still one for animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, svg

I'm trying to create an SVG animation of the letters E, D, and S. I have the JavaScript elsewhere in the file for animation, but it requires that all of the paths begin in the same place and branch off in different directions to create the letters.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 130.821 87.938">
 <linearGradient id="grad" x1="298" y1="0" x2="304" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <stop stop-color="#ddd" offset="0"/>
  <stop stop-color="#111" offset="0.01"/>
  <stop stop-color="#111" offset="0.7"/>
  <stop stop-color="#ddd" offset="0.7"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <g fill="none" stroke="url(#grad)" stroke-width="7.408239999999999"">
  <path d="M14.947 22.795l.082 38.443c16.467-.275 32.951.438 49.406-.502 4.717-1.167 9.144-3.87 12.234-7.623 3.127-5.011 4.014-11.665 1.11-16.988-1.62-3.331-3.98-6.636-7.709-7.742-6.395-2.218-13.296-2.331-19.994-2.068l-.088 27.165"/>
  <path d="M14.936 22.795v20.618h21.458"/>
  <path d="M14.936 22.795v3.703h27.14"/>
  <path d="M14.947 22.795l.082 38.443c16.465-.275 32.966.437 49.406-.502 4.51-.99 8.986-4.004 11.765-6.974 2.592-3.606 8.862 1.661 12.762 3.464 5.917 3.374 13.532 6.138 20.063 2.836 4.74-3.09 4.01-11.262-1.241-13.442-5.428-3.361-12.293-3.772-17.28-7.94-2.658-4.75 1.018-11.315 6.37-11.826 5.538-1.305 10.999 1.337 15.726 3.934"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Paste that in an HTML file and you'll see what I'm talking about with the paths overlapping at first, but branching off. Right now it looks like this:

[image: E D S Image]

Problem is, I need a break in between the S and the D. My first idea was to draw another line, the same color as my background, right in between the letters. This way, the whole path would be intact for the animation, but the user would only see the letters separated. Since I have some blurs and shadows on the page, it didn't turn out too well:

[image: E D S Image with break]

You can clearly see the path I drew in between the D and the S. How can I resolve this problem without breaking the path for animation? I can think of a few possible ways, but don't know how to accomplish any of them.

1. How could I change the stroke color of the path, mid-path? I could change it to the background color at the end of the D, and then back to the normal #eeeeee at the start of the S.
2. Possibly I could make the black path (which could be in another svg) higher than the light grey svg (using z-index?), but have the filters I have applied to the light grey svg be actually higher than the black path? It's hard to explain, but I'm just asking if you can set the z-index of a drop shadow CSS filter as different than the rest of the element.
3. Somehow set the transparency of the black path so it makes that section of the grey svg invisible (I don't know if that's even possible). It'd be like a CSS invisibilty cloak.

I think I could actually break the grey path into two, but I'd have to nail the timing of the animation for that to actually look alright. There's a lot more going on in the page than I explained, so that would take a very long time to get right. I'd love to hear everyone's suggestions before I go spend 20 hours on about as many pixels.

Comment: Check out SVG masking or clip-paths. They let you mask out a portion of a shape without having to modify the shape or have additional visual elements floating on top of your original shape. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask

Comment: Also stroke-dash-array - if you calculate the right array, it should put the break in the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this is what you need. Using the paths you have I'm creating a mask for the group. 
I'm using javascript and css for the animation. Your animation may be different.
Please take a look

```js
let animatedPaths = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("g path"));
animatedPaths.forEach(p=>{
  let l = p.getTotalLength();
  p.style.cssText = `stroke-dasharray:${l}; stroke-dashoffset:${l};`
  })
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid; width:100vh}
svg g path{transition:stroke-dashoffset 3s;}
svg:hover g path{stroke-dashoffset:0!important}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 130.821 87.938">
  <defs>
    <mask id="m">
       <path stroke="white" stroke-width="7.5"
          d="M14.936 22.795v3.703h27.14
                          M14.936 22.795v20.618h21.458
                          M14.947 22.795l.082 38.443c16.467-.275 32.951.438 49.406-.502 4.717-1.167 9.144-3.87 12.234-7.623 3.127-5.011 4.014-11.665 1.11-16.988-1.62-3.331-3.98-6.636-7.709-7.742-6.395-2.218-13.296-2.331-19.994-2.068l-.088 27.165
                          M14.947,22.795
                          L15.029,61.238
                          C31.494,60.963,47.995,61.675,64.435,60.736
                          C68.945,59.746,73.421,56.732,76.2,53.762
                          M88.962,57.226
                          C94.879,60.6,102.494,63.364,109.025,60.062
                          C113.765,56.972,113.035,48.8,107.784,46.62
                          C102.356,43.259,95.491,42.848,90.504,38.68
                          C87.846,33.93,91.522,27.365,96.874,26.854
                          C102.412,25.549,107.873,28.191,112.6,30.788" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
 <linearGradient id="grad" x1="298" y1="0" x2="304" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <stop stop-color="#ddd" offset="0"/>
  <stop stop-color="#111" offset="0.01"/>
  <stop stop-color="#111" offset="0.7"/>
  <stop stop-color="#ddd" offset="0.7"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <g fill="none" stroke="url(#grad)" stroke-width="7.4" style="mask: url(#m)">
  <path d="M14.947 22.795l.082 38.443c16.467-.275 32.951.438 49.406-.502 4.717-1.167 9.144-3.87 12.234-7.623 3.127-5.011 4.014-11.665 1.11-16.988-1.62-3.331-3.98-6.636-7.709-7.742-6.395-2.218-13.296-2.331-19.994-2.068l-.088 27.165
     M14.936 22.795v20.618h21.458
   M14.936 22.795v3.703h27.14
   M14.947 22.795l.082 38.443c16.465-.275 32.966 .437 49.406-.502c4.51-.99 8.986-4.004 11.765-6.974 c2.592-3.606 8.862 1.661 12.762 3.464 c5.917 3.374 13.532 6.138 20.063 2.836 c4.74-3.09 4.01-11.262 -1.241-13.442c-5.428-3.361 -12.293-3.772 -17.28-7.94c-2.658-4.75 1.018-11.315 6.37-11.826 c5.538-1.305 10.999 1.337 15.726 3.934"/>
     
     <path d="M14.936 22.795v3.703h27.14" />
                                                         
     
     
     <path d="M14.936 22.795v20.618h21.458" />
    
    <path d="M14.947 22.795l.082 38.443c16.467-.275 32.951.438 49.406-.502 4.717-1.167 9.144-3.87 12.234-7.623 3.127-5.011 4.014-11.665 1.11-16.988-1.62-3.331-3.98-6.636-7.709-7.742-6.395-2.218-13.296-2.331-19.994-2.068l-.088 27.165" />
    </g>
    
    
    
    
   
 
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.